# Odoo partner title is bool when is_company is True

Tags: python, xml, drop-down-menu, field, odoo-8

I have made some changes in Odoo to be able to format the partner name automatically. Now it seems that in the `res.partner` `title` field I can input both company and personal titles.

[image]

[image]

I use `title`, `name`, `first_name` and `last_name` to automatically format the name after input.

```
@api.one
@api.onchange("name", "title", "first_name", "last_name")
def onchange_name(self):
    if self.title and self.is_company:
        title = u" {}".format(self.title.name)
    elif self.title and not self.is_company:
        title = u"{} ".format(self.title.name)
    else:
        title = ""
    if self.first_name:
        first_name = self.first_name
    else:
        first_name = ""
    if self.last_name and self.first_name:
        last_name = u" {}".format(self.last_name)
    elif self.last_name:
        last_name = self.last_name
    else:
        last_name = ""

    if self.is_company:
        self.name = u"{0}{1}".format(self.name, title)
    else:
        self.name = u"{0}{1}{2}".format(title, first_name, last_name)
```

In the view I first removed the original `title` field and put it back where I wanted it to be.

```
            <field name="title" position="replace"></field>
            <xpath expr="//div[1]/div[1]" position="after">
                <div class="oe_edit_only" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company','=', False)]}">
                    <label for="title" string="Company Type"/>
                    <field name="title" class="oe_inline"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oe_edit_only" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company','=', True)]}">
                    <field name="title" style="width:20%%" options='{"no_open": True}' placeholder="Title"/>
                    <field name="first_name" style="width: 40%%" placeholder="First Name"/>
                    <field name="last_name" style="width: 40%%" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                </div>
            </xpath>
```

Of course it never works like you want it to be the first time. When I have `is_company` set to `False` everything works perfectly, but when `is_company` is set to `True` it doesn't work at all.

After debugging I found that when `is_company` is set to `False`, `title.name` is the value that is in the dropdown. But when `is_company` is set to `True` and I put a value into the `title` field the debuggers shows that the value is a boolean set to `False`.

If I save the value in the dropdown stays but when I debug again it still is a boolean set to `False`.

Could someone help me to fix this?